# How to transpose a long data frame every n rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame like this:

```
x=data.frame(type = c('a','b','c','a','b','a','b','c'),
value=c(5,2,3,2,10,6,7,8))
```

every item has attributes a, b, c while some records may be missing records, i.e. only have a and b

The desired output is

```
y=data.frame(item=c(1,2,3), a=c(5,2,6), b=c(2,10,7), c=c(3,NA,8))
```

How can I transform x to y? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
out <- dcast(setDT(x),  rowid(type) ~ type, value.var = 'value')
setnames(out, 'type', 'item')
out
#   item a  b  c
#1:    1 5  2  3
#2:    2 2 10  8
#3:    3 6  7 NA
```

Comment: Is the answer correct? I thought the NA should be in row 2 with values a=2, b=10?

Answer (score 1):

Create a grouping vector `g` assuming each occurrence of `a` starts a new group, use `tapply` to create a table `tab` and coerce that to a data frame.  No packages are used.

```
g <- cumsum(x$type == "a")
tab <- with(x, tapply(value, list(g, type), c))
as.data.frame(tab)
```

giving:

```
  a  b  c
1 5  2  3
2 2 10 NA
3 6  7  8
```

An alternate definition of the grouping vector which is slightly more complex but would be needed if some groups have `a` missing is the following.  It assumes that `x` lists the `type` values in order of their levels within group so that if a level is less than the prior level it must be the start of a new group.

```
g <- cumsum(c(-1, diff(as.numeric(x$type))) < 0)
```

Note that ultimately there must be some restriction on missingness; otherwise, the problem is ambiguous.  For example if one group can have `b` and `c` missing and then next group can have `a` missing then whether `b` and `c` in the second group actually form a second group or are part of the first group is not determinable.

Comment: It really seems like this should work `x %>% 
  mutate(item = group_indices(., type)) %>% 
  spread(type, value, -item) ` but it doesn't

Comment: @Grothendieck: This would be tidier, I think: `x %>%  mutate(item = cumsum(type =="a") ) %>%  spread(type, value)` Would you mind posting it, or would you mind if I did?